# Sabre Instaflights Search API only pulling Basic Economy Fares

Tags: api, sabre

I am testing the Instaflights Search API to pull fare information for an airline. In this example, using Delta. When I pull the data, I only get the pricing for the Basic Economy and not for Main Cabin or First class. Is there a way to get access to these prices or we are limited to the lowest price? I compared the results with the Delta website and only the flights with Basic Economy seats matched between the API and the airline site.

Answer (score 0):

InstaFligths, retrieves roundtrip or one-way flight itineraries with published fares and fare breakdowns for a given city pair and departure date. The API returns the 300 of the lowest-priced itineraries.

If looking to retrieve different Brands or Cabin Types, please look into Bargain Finder Max API.

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_apis/air/search/bargain_finder_max